# android studio LinearLayout image starting point

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am very new to android programming and I am now trying to position a "circle ball" image file into the `LinearLayout` in the middle. So, I have tried making 7 LinearLayouts equally divided and I am trying to put an image at the bottom of the 4th `LinearLayout`. The code below shows that I have 7 `LinearLayouts`. How can I put a "circle ball" image at the bottom of the 4th LinearLayout? Also, is creating 7 `LinearLayouts` a good idea? The purpose of the ball would be to move the ball to the next `LinearLayout` when I click "next" `Button`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout6"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout7"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Draw, take a screenshot or something showing what do you need to do because... i'm really don't understand you...

Comment: use weight sum in parent linear

Comment: DO YOU WANT THAT IMAGE IN BOTTOM OR IN MIDDLE ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout you have posted is very badly designed layout. If image is all you want to show on the screen then directly just put the image in the `LinearLayout` and set layout's `gravity` to `center`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match+parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or, if there are other views too in your layout and you want the image to be placed in the `center` then use `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I wanted to move the ball by clicking a button to the next linear layout after I place the ball in the middle of the screen. That is why I created 7 linear layouts and tried to place the ball at the 4th one, which is the middle.

Comment: Then use relative layout, put image in center, and animate the ball on button click

Answer (score 0):

Using **RelativLayout** add `Imageview` as done below, if you want to move that image than for that **You can use the onClick method** and in that method **change the src of the image views.**

```
myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
```

---

change your layout to :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="100"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is this answer helped ?@Eric

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is not a good approach having 7 nested layouts. If you want a view to be moved dynamically (let's say on click) you could use relative layout and then attach onClickListener to that view.